# JAVA. Trying to create a LinkedListStack to solve a mathematical expression.. Issue with the variable types

Tags: java

JAVA. I am trying to create a LinkedListStack to solve a mathematical expression. Ex: (1 + 2) * 4 - 3. I am having trouble with the different variable types saying that they are incompatible. There is an issue with the pop and peek methods I wrote and I cannot figure out how to get them to work. I cannot use the Java LinkedList or Stack classes, so I had to write the LLNode class and LinkedList class.
Here are the errors I am getting:

```
Line 120:method Peek in class LinkedList<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: Character. found: no arguments. reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class LinkedList 
Line 121:')' expected. not a statement. method Peek in class LinkedList<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: Character. found: no arguments. reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class LinkedList 
Line 122:';' expected method Peek in class LinkedList<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: Character. found: no arguments. reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class LinkedList 
Line 134:method Peek in class LinkedList<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: Character. found: no arguments. reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class LinkedList 
Line 135:method Peek in class LinkedList<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: Character. found: no arguments. reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class LinkedList 
Line 153: method Peek in class LinkedList<T> cannot be applied to given types; required: Character. found: no arguments. reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class LinkedList  
Line 175:incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int 
Line 183:incompatible types: void cannot be converted to char
Line 185:incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int 
Line 187:incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
```

Here is what I have so far:
Thank you so much in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
//class for linked list node
    class LLNode<T>
    {
        protected T info; //create a variable info of object T
        protected LLNode<T> link; //create a variable link of object LLNode<T>
        
        //constructor
        public LLNode(T info)  
        {
            this.info=info; //initialize info to current object
            link=null; //set the link to null 
        }
        //method to put info into the node 
        public void setInfo(T info)
        {
            this.info=info; //initialize info to current object 
        }
        //method to get info from the node
        public T getInfo()
        {
            return info; //returns info
        }
        //method to link node to the next node
        public void setLink(LLNode<T> link) //method to link nodes together into a list 
        {
            this.link=link; //link node to current object 
        }
        //method to get the link from the node
        public LLNode<T> getLink()
        {
            return link; //returns the link 
        }   
    }
    
    //class for linked list 
    class LinkedList<T>
    {
        protected LLNode<T> top; //reference to the top of the stack 
        
        //method to check if the stack is empty
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return(top==null); //sets the top to null
        }
        //method to check if the stack is full
        public boolean isFull()
        {
            return false; //false since a linked list stack cannot be full
        }
        //LinkedList method
        public LinkedList()
        {
            top=null; //sets the top to null 
        }
        //method to push an element onto the stack 
        public void push(T element)
        {
            LLNode<T> newNode=new LLNode<T>(element); //create newNode of object LLNode<T>
            newNode.setLink(top); //links new node to the top element
            top=newNode; //sets the top to the new node 
        }
        //method to remove an element from the stack
        public void pop()
        {
            if(isEmpty()) //check if stack is empty
                throw new EmptyStackException(); //throws exception if stack is empty
            else
                top=top.getLink(); //sets the top to the next element
        }
        //method to peek at the next element without removing it 
        public T peek(T element)
        {
            element=top.getInfo(); //checks the info in the top element
            return element; //returns the info 
        }
    }
//class to evaluate the expression     
public class EvaluateExpression
{
    //main method 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); //create new Scanner object
        //ask the user to enter the expression 
        System.out.println("Enter the expression with spaces between each " 
                + "character entered: ");
        //set info user entered to the expression variable 
        String expression=keyboard.nextLine();
        //call the evaluateExpression method and display result to user 
        System.out.println("The result of the expression: " + expression + 
                " is: " + evaluateExpression(expression));
    }
    //method to evaluate the expression 
    public static int evaluateExpression(String expression)
    {
    //create a new LinkedList for the operands
    LinkedList<Integer> operandStack=new LinkedList<>();
    //create a new LinkedList for the operators 
    LinkedList<Character> operatorStack=new LinkedList<>();
    //create an array to hold the values the user entered by splitting the String
    //into individual operators and operands 
    String[] elements=expression.split("\\s+");
    //for loop to go through elements
    for(String element : elements)
    {
        //if there is a blank space then continue to the while loop
        if(element.length()==0)
            continue;
        //checks if the element is a + or - operator 
        else if(element.charAt(0)=='+'|| element.charAt(0)=='-')
        {
            //while the stack is not empty and the element is a operator
            while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && (operatorStack.peek() == '+' || 
                    operatorStack.peek()--'-' || operatorStack.peek() == '*' 
                    || operatorStack.peek() == '/'))
            {
                //call the calulcate method to process operators 
                calculate(operandStack, operatorStack);
            }
            //push the operator onto the operator stack 
            operatorStack.push(element.charAt(0));
        }
        //checks if the element is a * or / operator 
        else if(element.charAt(0)=='*' || element.charAt(0)=='/')
        {
            //while the stack is not empty and the element is a * or /
            while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && (operatorStack.peek() == '*' 
                    || operatorStack.peek() == '/'))
            {
                //call the calculate method to process * or / operators 
               calculate(operandStack, operatorStack);
            }
        //push the operator to the operator stack 
        operatorStack.push(element.charAt(0));
        }
        //check if the element is a ( operator 
        else if (element.charAt(0)=='(')
        {
            //pushes the ( onto the operator stack 
            operatorStack.push('(');
        }
        //check if the element is a ) operator 
        else if(element.charAt(0)==')')
        {
            //while the operator is not (
            while(operatorStack.peek() !='(')
                {
                //call calculate method to process operators until ( operator 
                calculate(operandStack, operatorStack);
                }
                //pop ( operator from the stack 
                operatorStack.pop();
        }
        //check if the element is an operand 
        else
        {
            //push the operand to the operand stack 
            operandStack.push(new Integer(element));
        }
    }
    //check if the stack is not empty
    while(!operatorStack.isEmpty())
    {
        //call the calculate method to process operators 
        calculate(operandStack, operatorStack);
    }
    //return the final result 
    return operandStack.pop();
    }
    
    //method to calculate the operator and the 2 operands on the top of the stack
    public static void calculate(LinkedList<Integer> operandStack, 
            LinkedList<Character> operatorStack)
    {
        //declare a variable ch and initialize to call pop method 
        char ch = operatorStack.pop(); 
        //declare a variable value1 and initialize to call pop method
        int value1 = operandStack.pop();
        //declare a variable value2 and initialize to call pop method 
        int value2 = operandStack.pop();
        //if element is +
        if (ch == '+')
            //add the 2 values
            operandStack.push(value2 + value1);
        //if element is -
        else if (ch == '-')
            //subtract the 2 values
            operandStack.push(value2 - value1);
        //if element is *
        else if (ch == '*')
            //multiply the 2 values
            operandStack.push(value2 * value1);
        //if element is / 
        else if (ch == '/')
            //divide the 2 values
            operandStack.push(value2 / value1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should update your question to include the exact error you are getting including the line number so people trying to help you don't have to guess.

Comment: ...yes.  Please very clearly define "having trouble with the different variable types saying that they are incompatible".  Provide some clear examples of these troubles you're having, in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I will update it right now

Comment: I added the errors I am getting to the original question, thank you

Comment: I see some obvious problems with your code where your calls to your LinkedList methods don't line up with their definitions.  You call `peek` with no parameters but it is defined as taking one parameter, and you expect a return value from `pop` but that method does not return a value.  These simple, obvious mistakes are at least partly the cause of your errors. - Please fix these obvious syntactical problems so you/we can focus on the more interesting parts of your question.

Comment: ...I couldn't wait :). I fixed the problems I speak of above, and one other simple issue, and your code works great!  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I fix the obvious problems with your code, it runs, and it give me no errors.  It even seems to give the right answer for the simple expressions I tried.

The main changes I made were to fix your `peek` and `pop` methods.  The fixed versions are these:

```
public T pop()
{
    if(isEmpty()) //check if stack is empty
        throw new EmptyStackException(); //throws exception if stack is empty
    LLNode<T> r = top;
    top=top.getLink();
    return r.getInfo();
}

public T peek()
{
    T element=top.getInfo(); //checks the info in the top element
    return element; //returns the info
}
```

I also fixed a place where you had `--` when you obviously wanted `==`.

After making these simple changes, your code runs pretty well.  Here are some example runs:

```
Enter the expression with spaces between each character entered: 
3 * 5
The result of the expression: 3 * 5 is: 15

Enter the expression with spaces between each character entered: 
2 * 3 + 4
The result of the expression: 2 * 3 + 4 is: 10

Enter the expression with spaces between each character entered: 
12 - 2 * 4
The result of the expression: 12 - 2 * 4 is: 4
```

You still have some issues, like the fact that in one of the two methods above, you don't check for an empty stack, but in the other you do.  But in general, this is nice work!

Comment: Thank you so so much. I really appreciate it!

Comment: So glad I could help @sus378.  If this answered your question, please click the Check Mark to the left of it to indicate that it did.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with your thinking about the stack itself.

You don't have a one stack for operators and another for operands.

It's one stack for the whole thing.

Comment: Does this not create 2 stacks?                                                                 
     LinkedList<Integer> operandStack=new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Character> operatorStack=new LinkedList<>();                                                            Sorry this problem was very confusing for me :\

Comment: It does.  I don't think that's correct.  One stack would be my suggestion.  The type should be String.